# Rails lib load order

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have the following classes in my applications lib directory:

proxy.rb

```
class Proxy
end
```

ga_proxy.rb

```
class GaProxy < Proxy
  include GaProxy::Metrics
end
```

metrics.rb

```
class GaProxy
  module Metrics
  end
end
```

Load order clearly matters here:

metrics.rb need to be loaded before ga_proxy.rb

proxy.rb needs to be loaded before ga_proxy.rb

But if metrics.rb is loaded before ga_proxy, then I get 'superclass mismatch for class GaProxy' because GaProxy has already been defined without a parent class.

How can I get around this issue?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `application.rb` file, specify each file you want to load in order:

```
config.autoload_paths += %W( #{config.root}/lib/proxy.rb, #{config.root}/lib/metrics.rb, #{config.root}/lib/ga_proxy.rb )
```

Answer (score 0):

I've never had this issue but why can't you do the following in config/initializers

create a file  config/initializers/libs.rb

```
 require 'proxy'
 require 'ga_proxy'
 require 'metrics'
```

Answer (score 0):

Generally, in ruby, you require what you need in your file:

```
# ga_proxy.rb
require './proxy'
require './metrics'

class GaProxy < Proxy
  include GaProxy::Metrics
end
```

That's assuming the files live in the same directory. Of course, Rails does some autoloading magic for you, but you can still be explicit about your requires.

**Edit**

You'll have to specify the superclass in `metrics.rb`:

```
# metrics.rb
class GaProxy < Proxy
  module Metrics
  end
end
```